# No error, and No changes in the Database

Tags: php

I need to set the classid's of the checked checkboxes to be PAID
and the non-checked to be UNPAID.
What can be the problem that is preventing database changing?
Im checking some checkboxes in the html page.
When i press Save the page resets and when i check the database(PhpMyAdmin) there are no changes.

Here's my code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  ?> <input type="hidden" name="id1[]" value="<?php echo $row['classid']; ?>" /><?php
 echo "<td>"  . $row['class_date'] .  "</td>";
    echo "<td>"  . $row['class_time'] .  "</td>";
   echo "<td>"  . $row['sal_teach'] .  "</td>";
   echo "<td align=center>"  . $row['status_teach'] .  "</td>"; ?>
   <!--echo "<td><a href='getpaid2.php?id={$row['classid']}'>Get Paid</a></td>";-->
  <td align="center"><input name="ONOFF[<?php echo $row['classid']; ?>]" type="checkbox" /></td>
<?php
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "<tr><td colspan=5><input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Save'/></td></tr>";
  echo "</table></div>";

    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

  foreach($_POST['id1'] as $id1)
 { 
  $status1 = 'UNPAID';
    if (isset($_POST['ONOFF'][$id1]))
    {
        $status1 = 'PAID';
    }

  $sql1="UPDATE class SET status_teach='$status1' WHERE classid=$id1";  

$myconn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Couldn't Connect to the Server");
mysql_select_db('bddschool', $myconn) or die ("message");
  mysql_query($sql1,$mycon);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should Be :

```
if (isset($_POST['ONOFF'][$id1])) {
    $status1 = 'PAID';
} else {
    $status1 = 'UNPAID';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox is missing a value. It is always empty.

```
<input name="ONOFF[<?php echo $row['classid']; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Comment: I added value='1' and still no changes in database. The syntax of the SQL query is fine i tried it in Phpmyadmin sql interface and it worked.

Comment: Is the form really a POST or a GET form?

Comment: POST form...in all my project i'm using Post form

Comment: <FORM name ="form" method ="post" action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?> ">

Comment: i m not sure but put your database connectinn code in top of the page before query and then try.